# What survival model is suitable for not comparing groups?

Tags: survival, cox-model

I initially used Cox PH model for my data for different subgroups of my population, however I do not want to make any comparisons between groups, rather i need to describe the time to event for each one. Other than just using KM curves, is there a model to describe the effects of covariate on a time to event?

Comment: If you want an estimate of mean time to event in the presence of censoring you could consider a parametric survival model.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Cox regression more closely. Simply put, you can put in categorical variables (in this case "groups"). Then, the hazard rate can be obtained for each group relative to reference group (in other words, the reference group will have no hazard rate).

Answer (score 0):

The effect of a covariate is, by definition, a difference between two groups. To know what it does, I must compare the expected outcome to that among those who do not express the covariate. A hazard ratio can be a non-parametric summary of the difference between two survival curves. Whether you choose to report the inferential findings is a matter of preference. You can report the median survival (which is a direct result from the Kaplan Meier curves) for each covariate group as another way of presenting clear, tangible statistics. You can present area under the survival curve (an estimate of mean survival).